# How to divide Wikipedia file and use for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have downloaded Wikipedia and I thought that it will be `.json` file, but it's `.nt`. Is there any difference between those two?
Plus, it's 77 GB of data, so it takes time to open this file. Do you have any idea how to divide this data into smaller parts so I can work on it?

Comment: What did you download and from where? I'd be suspicious of that file format unless it came from a legitimate source eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: ".nt" looks like a windows file - https://file.org/extension/nt 

You might want to consider using this npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wikipedia

Comment: Yes, agreed. Unless the file has been renamed, I wouldn't be expecting ".nt" file extension. I'm unaware that Wikipedia provide downloads in that file format which is why I'd be suspicious.

Comment: I have seen the `.nt` extension used for N-Triples. I would look at the head lines of the file and see if it looks like this `<url> ns:tag <url>.` I don't know if WP has SW datasets for download if it does you might have downloaded the wrong data.

Comment: Yeah, Wikidata has `.nt` downloads: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/

Comment: Also JSON downloads right next to it, if Wikidata entity data is what you were looking for. You'll have to deal with the file size yourself, though. There are a couple streaming JSON parsers.